# How process variables in Pelican templates?

Tags: jinja2, pelican

I define a variable in a pelican article using for instance Markdown syntax:

```
Motto: _"Paranoia is a virtue"_  Anonymous, 1984
```

Then I want to use it in a template (ex. article.html) as:

```
 {% if article.motto %}<p>{{ article.motto }}</p>{% endif %}
```

I, obviously, obtain in HTML something like:

```
 <p>_"Paranoia is a virtue"_  Anonymous, 1984</p>
```

Is there a way to process the variable (f.i. through a Jinja filter) to obtain the text after Markdown processing. In the case the result should be:

```
 <p><i>"Paranoia is a virtue"</i>  Anonymous, 1984</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your `pelicanconf.py` file to define a Jinja filter to pass the variable through `markdown`:

```py
from markdown import Markdown
markdown = Markdown(extensions=['markdown.extensions.extra'])

def md(content, *args):
    return markdown.convert(content)

JINJA_FILTERS = {
    'md': md,
}
```

Then you can do

`{% if article.motto %}<p>{{ article.motto | md }}</p>{% endif %}`

and your variable will be properly rendered.

Answer (score 2):

For 3.5, no. Markdown doesn't process metadata by default. But the current development version includes a new setting, [`FORMATTED_FIELDS`](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/master/docs/settings.rst), for that. So, wait for 3.6 or install the dev-version from github.

Of course, you can also use HTML instead of markdown syntax:

```
Motto: <i>"Paranoia is a virtue"</i>  Anonymous, 1984
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the trick?

```
{% if article.motto %}<p>{{ article.motto | replace("_", "<i>", 1) | replace("_", "</i>" }}</p>{% endif %}
```